# Textarea with button on same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea v-model="notes" maxlength="1000" class="form-control" row="2" :disabled="laptop.scrapped !== 0">
            </textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" :disabled="!notes">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-right button">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Return</button>
        <button class="btn">Select and Return</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Results in this:

[image]

I had to add the following CSS to get the buttons to sit on the bottom and not float in the middle, and I wonder if this has something to do with it:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: <div class="row"> : you must wrapped it like (width:500px or any unit) then 
<div class="col-sm-4 text-right button">: width:100% -> your-button will sit on the bottom of BOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use `Flexbox` with media queries instead of `absolute` positioning. [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/705/)

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .row.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
}
```

Comment: That works nicely - thanks. I think flexbox may be solution to all my (many, MANY) Bootstrap woes, but I don't quite understand it at the moment.

Comment: You're welcome, you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea v-model="notes" maxlength="1000" class="form-control" row="2" :disabled="laptop.scrapped !== 0">
        </textarea>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" :disabled="!notes">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 text-right button">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Return</button>
    <button class="btn">Select and Return</button>
</div>
```

and the new code for class clear is:

```
  .clear {clear: both;}
```

Now the button will always placed at bottom not float in middle.

Answer (score 0):

If i m correct you want the save button next to textarea.

Having a `class="form-control"`on `textarea` will make it take the whole width.
Removing the class the code is as below :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea v-model="notes" maxlength="1000"  row="2" :disabled="laptop.scrapped !== 0">
            </textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" :disabled="!notes">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-right button">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Return</button>
        <button class="btn">Select and Return</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the Save Button will be placed exactly next `textarea` . You can use `margin` and `padding` to position it properly the way u like.

EDIT for aligned buttons:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea v-model="notes" maxlength="1000" row="2" :disabled="laptop.scrapped !== 0">
            </textarea>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:-30px;">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-right button">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Return</button>
        <button class="btn">Select and Return</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the standard Bootsrap input styling without it taking the whole column? The solution I accepted above does at least all me to have all the buttons nicely aligned on the bottom.

Comment: @daninthemix check the Edit i made. U can make smaller collumns and edit its content individually.